# Android Spinner remove OnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-2.3-gingerbread

Others has the problem as doesn't working, I have the problem it is working ( and it shouldn't )

I have a data model, which is saved, and need to loaded back to GUI, Activity. It has a few spinner value.

The data is place to a common accesible class, a reference holder.

The activity's onCreate it will check if is on edit mode or not with:

```
editMode = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EDIT_MODE_KEY, false);
```

It will load the UI elements from xml, and start selecting, filling values. 
At editing mode, and at creation mode it should select values what has the data model.
At runtime ( after onResume() )  has some workflow: is something is selected at spinner1, than should refresh the spinner2 adapter content and so on.

It doesn't worked the plain `.setSelection(positiontoSelect);` so I have added a delayed post, now is working.

My problem is: I would like remove for temp the selection listener, call the selection and add back the listener.

Here is the code, which should be modified:

```
          if (editedTimezonePosition > -1) {                        
                final int positiontoSelect = editedTimezonePosition;
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        OnItemSelectedListener listener = spSelectTimezone.getOnItemSelectedListener();
                        spSelectTimezone.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
                        spSelectTimezone.setSelection(positiontoSelect);
                        spSelectTimezone.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);                   
                    }
                }, 250);            
            }
```

setting to null the listener has no effect:  I am getting callback to my listener method.

If you have any idea how to fix it, please share it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a counter variable in your `onItemSelected` method.  If it is 0 (meaning the first time the method has been called), do nothing but increment the variable.  If it is greater than 0, execute the rest of your code.

```
private int mSpinnerSelectionCount=0;

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int pos, long id) {
        if(mSpinnerSelectionCount == 0){
            mSpinnerSelectionCount++;
        } else {
            // Your normal selection code here
        }    
    }
```

Comment: +1, good idea. I will try it. As to improve: I can write a setter for mSpinnerSelectionCount and in this way fixing the android os bugs? :) Use the setter with 0 value, when I need to disable

Comment: Actually, in your case I would just use a `boolean` (with your aforementioned setter method).  My example method is an `int` because I pulled it from some code I had handy where I needed to track the number of times a selection was made on a spinner.  :)

Comment: it is working and I am using the setter: set to 0, -1 and I am checking if is under 1 :)